# How to display results duplicate rows in the same table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible to display lines that have duplicates in the same table?
I tried to make this query on sql developer but it is still searching for a while without giving me results or even error message, here is my last query I tried so far :

```
SELECT foo.COL_1, foo.COL_2, foo.COL_3, foo.COL_4, foo.COL_5, foo.COL_6, foo.COL_7
FROM TABLE_NAME foo
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT bar.COL_1, bar.COL_2, bar.COL_3, bar.COL_4, bar.COL_5, bar.COL_6, bar.COL_7
              FROM TABLE_NAME bar
              WHERE foo.COL_1 = bar.COL_1
              AND foo.COL_2 = bar.COL_2
              AND foo.COL_3 = bar.COL_3
              AND foo.COL_4 = bar.COL_4
              AND foo.COL_5 = bar.COL_5
              AND foo.COL_6 = bar.COL_6
              AND foo.COL_7 = bar.COL_7
              GROUP BY bar.COL_1, bar.COL_2, bar.COL_3, bar.COL_4, bar.COL_5, bar.COL_6, bar.COL_7)
GROUP BY foo.COL_1, foo.COL_2, foo.COL_3, foo.COL_4, foo.COL_5, foo.COL_6, foo.COL_7
ORDER BY foo.COL_7
;
```

**Note :** 
I don't need to see a line with a count that tells me that it exists in 2 or more times, Otherwise I would have put primary key to prevent duplicates. I have to print this data on a report.
 I will only like the posted ones.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `COUNT` as an analytic function here:

```
SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4, COL_5, COL_6, COL_7
FROM
(
    SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4, COL_5, COL_6, COL_7,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4, COL_5,
                       COL_6, COL_7) cnt
    FROM TABLE_NAME
) t
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY COL_7;
```

This will display *all* records which have duplicates.  If you instead want only one record from each duplicate group, then we can modify the above query.